# Intermittant "Server does not exist or access denied"

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sql-server-2000, linked-server

Recently had a server die and had to rebuild it from backups.  Now I'm getting intermittent failures from several of my Access applications (which work using linked tables and passthrough queries).  I also have another SQL server that is linked to the restored one, and many of the stored procedures include calls over this link.

Main problem is that the error messages are so generic, I can't even tell which of my 2 SQL Server's it can't reach.  Most of the time it seems that some of the passthrough stored procedures run, but with some failures.

How can I tell which SQL server is not available?  How can I troubleshoot and correct this issue as its intermittent and does not always fail?

Error:
[image]

EDIT: Any way to make this error message give me more information????

Comment: Did the server OS change versions? Did you rebuild the ODBC connections or just plug into the existing ones?

Comment: Server OS is the same.  We named the new server the same as the old so we could use the same client DSNs.

Comment: Did the IP address change or were you able to reuse it?

Comment: Used the same static IP, but the DSNs use the hostname.

Answer (score 1):

These can be tough to diagnose and fix at times. If it were me I would start with removing and re-building the ODBC connections and treating it like a fresh application install. Double check all firewalls, network paths etc...Once you are sure all of the connections are open, ports are clear, usrname/pwd's all work and then start going through the SP's one at a time to see which ones kick off the error. From there you should be able to identify the parameter or value that is being incorrectly passed, most likely due to an unknown change that happened when the server was rebuilt.

Another thing to check is patch levels and add on software that is installed. No telling what was either snuck in or was not on your backup images and needs to be added

Comment: Could using the hostname instead of the IP cause this kind of instability?  Is there any point changing the DNS to use the IP?

Comment: It could, depending on how the connection string operates. If one particular call is looking for IP instead of the DNS or vice-versa etc...

Comment: having fought with things like this for years my strategy is to now just burn down the house and rebuild

Comment: Sry, I meant "DSN", which is how all the connections are happening.  Odbcad32.exe and such.

Comment: I would start with the SP's you think are failing and look for what they are calling. If the names are right, start looking at account and directory permissions. Some perms might not have been reassigned

Comment: Not sure what you mean by directory permissions... can you explain?